# Create columns based on a categorical column and values from another column

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this

```
Weight  Sex
91.0    male
91.0    male
131.0   female
128.0   female
132.0   female
150.0   male
```

I want something like

```
male   female
91.0     0
91.0     0
0        131.0
0        128.0
0        132.0
150.0     0
```

How can I achieve this without using pd.wide_to_long() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with no `index` parameter and then replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df.pivot(columns='Sex', values='Weight').fillna(0)
print (df)
Sex  female   male
0       0.0   91.0
1       0.0   91.0
2     131.0    0.0
3     128.0    0.0
4     132.0    0.0
5       0.0  150.0
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Sex', append=True)['Weight'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
Sex  female   male
0       0.0   91.0
1       0.0   91.0
2     131.0    0.0
3     128.0    0.0
4     132.0    0.0
5       0.0  150.0
```

If order of columns is important add subset:

```
df = df.pivot(columns='Sex', values='Weight').fillna(0)[['male','female']]
print (df)
Sex   male  female
0     91.0     0.0
1     91.0     0.0
2      0.0   131.0
3      0.0   128.0
4      0.0   132.0
5    150.0     0.0
```

Comment: @Erfan If you think `pivot` dupe  I think not. If think something else, then possible